# SharePoint Json formatting

Tags: json, sharepoint, calculated-columns

Hopefully someone can shed some light on an issue I am having, I have 3 columns in a SharePoint list. One is the number of days for a task to be completed (i.e 5) the second is the calculated date (i.e todays date + 5) the third displays a count down of days. I have tried formatting this column with JSON with no success. What I would like to do is have the text or background green for 4 and 5 days yellow for 3 and 2 days and red for 1 day.

This is the JSON that forms the count down column, for the formatting I tried to use indexof to find 1 day(s) but that didn't work? maybe because the actual value is displayed as a date?

Hopefully this makes sense? and I hope I have not missed something glaringly obvious?

{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "=floor((Number(@currentField)-Number(Date((getMonth(@now)+1)+'.'+getDate(@now)+'.'+getYear(@now))))/(60*60*24*1000))+' day(s) remaining'"
}

Answer (score 0):

To achieve dynamic countdown column, you need to integrate your list with power automate flow. Column formatted using JSON won't refresh the value every day and it is a static value only if when there is a refresh item action.

See this thread: [Create Dynamic Countdown in SharePoint List items](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-Dynamic-Countdown-in-SharePoint-List-items/td-p/1339578).